# read a String in a text file

Tags: java, bufferedreader, file-handling

let's say I have this text in my text file:

```
VOTED/1/hannah/18
NOT VOTING/2/janice/20
```

and I have this code:

```
File Orig_outFile = new File("C:\\voters.txt");
BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Orig_outFile));

vNum=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter voters number: ");
String line="";
String something="VOTED";
while(infile.readLine()!=null){
    line=infile.readLine();
    String [] info=line.split("/");

    if(info[1].matches(vNum)){
    while(info[0].matches(something)){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Voter already voted or Voter not registered. Please try again");
        vNum=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter voters number: ");
    }
    President();
    }
}
infile.close();
```

the task is the user needs to enter a voter's number, then read the text file, and then if it is found that the `info[0]` in the text file contains `VOTED` it will get error message and needs to enter its voter's number again. I'm assuming that my mistake here is I'm using the while loop twice?

Comment: This code will leak the `infile` resource in the event of an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you are reading a line in `while` by doing `infile.readLine()` and appending next line to String `line` by doing `infile.readLine()` again.

You are ending up reading just the second line from your file. You should change your while loop as follows:

```
while((line = infile.readLine()) != null)
```

And remove the below statement:

```
line = infile.readLine();
```

Here is the corrected code snippet:

```
File Orig_outFile = new File("C:\\voters.txt");
BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Orig_outFile));

vNum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter voters number: ");
String line = null;
String something = "VOTED";
while((line = infile.readLine()) != null) {
    String [] info = line.split("/");

    /* Assuming You Are Entering Voter's Number & Not Voter's Name */
    if(info[1].equalsIgnoreCase(vNum)) {
        if(info[0].equalsIgnoreCase(something)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Voter already voted or 
                                          Voter not registered. Please try again");
            /* Please Note That You Are Currently Iterating File */
            /* If You Do This Here, You'll End Up Checking Same Records */
            /* You'll Have To Replace Outer `if` with `while` */
            vNum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter voters number: ");
        } else {
            President();
            break;
        }
    }
}
infile.close();
```

Here is a much clearer approach to implement it:

1. Read the complete file in memory (preferably `Map` with key -> Voter Number).
2. Take the Voter Number from user and check if it exists in the Map.
3. If it does not exist in Map or if the value equals `VOTED` then repeat `Step 2`.

Here is the code snippet:

```
File Orig_outFile = new File("C:\\voters.txt");
BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Orig_outFile));
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
String something = "VOTED";

String line = null;
while((line = infile.readLine()) != null) {
    String [] info = line.split("/");
    map.add(info[1],info[0]);
}
infile.close();

while(true) {
    vNum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Voter's Number: ");
    if(map.contains(info[1]) && !map.get(info[1]).equalsIgnoreCase(something)) {
        President();
        break;
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Voter already voted or 
                                          Voter not registered. Please try again");
    }
}
```

Comment: oh nothing really happened. it is still the same like it won't even read the text file or something like that. it will skip the the if and while condition and just go to the President() method

Comment: @pep I hope you are entering something like `18` as the Voter Number instead of Voter Name. In that case shouldn't it be `info[2]` instead of `info[1]`?

Comment: oh i just noticed and i edited now my question. actually the voter's number is in info[1] and the info[3] or the 18 is the age :) and yes i will try this and i'll let you know if it works :)

Comment: @pep You should read the file in memory first and then take the input from user. Check the updated solution.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `infile.readLine()` actually reads a line from the file, returns it and moves to the next line. You are calling it twice, once in the while loop condition:

```
while(infile.readLine() != null)
```

And again in the first line in the loop:

```
line = infile.readLine();
```

You should just call it once in the while loop condition and assign the value to `line` variable, like so:

```
while((line = infile.readLine()) != null)
```

Comment: I thought I have mentioned the same thing in my answer below?